# How correctly Open "div" by ID ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

for simplicity. , I map a bdd,

I display the result in a card, it creates several card,

I have a button when I click it opens the rest of the map.

my problem and the next one, when I click it opens all the cards.

I would only like to open by ID

How can I fix this issue?thx all

make room for the code

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  isToggle: false
    }; 
 
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

   handleClick = (id) => {
    this.setState({isToggle: !this.state.isToggle });
  }
```

chat.id = MyMap

```
  return (
         <div key={chat.id}>
                <div>
                    <div key={chat.id}>
                        <Button onClick={() => {this.handleClick(chat.id)}}> {chat.id}</Button>                          
                    </div>
                </div>

  <div style={{display: this.state.isToggle ? 'block': 'none'}} key={chat.id}>     
  <p> {chat.a} </p> 
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your `isToggle` is a boolean and all your divs are setting their display css prop to `'block'` or `'none'` based on that boolean.

What I've done in similar cases is set the `isToggle` to be a number value (initialstate to -1 or some value that will never match the chat.id), then in your `div` style you can do

`{{display: this.state.isToggle === chat.id ? 'block': 'none'}}`

Then in your `handleClick` you do

```
handleClick = (id) => {
     this.setState({isToggle: id });
   }
```

If you wanted to be able to toggle the item on click when it's already active, you could do

```
  handleClick = (id) => {
         this.setState({isToggle: this.state.isToggle === id ? -1 : id });
       }
```

This assumes your `chat.id` is a number value but you could do the same with a string value and set the initial state to `""`.